# Launch webpage in sublime text 2

Tags: ide, sublimetext2

I am new to sublime text 2.

I wanted to know how can I browse my web page in sublime text 2.

Earlier I was using Visual Studio where I can right-click on a web page and view it in browser of choice. It either used IIS express or it's in built Cassini web server for this.

I need same functionality with sublime. Please guide me how I can I acheive that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package for that: https://github.com/adampresley/sublime-view-in-browser

May be installed with [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) using the standard way. Search for `View in browser`.

Comment: Thanks Sergey for the reply. However I have a question here considering I am using nginx. For opening the website in localhost as given in the documentation of view in browser do I need to create a nginx configuration file for each project I create in sublime

Comment: @Mozak pity to say, I can't answer your second question. Most probably yes, but as currently almost every web language uses some kind of interpreter and url parser, you'll not find it useful. I recommend you to look for something called [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/). Never used it but some say it works with ST very nicely

Comment: I guess I will go with view in browser for now and will try to figure out with nginx issue later. Thanks again :)